# call method and Variable in the MainActivity class

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to put  the inner BroadcastReceiverListener in the MainActivity, which works well there, in serperate class. The problem I do not know how can I invoke the method"deliverBestAccessPoint(updatedResults)" from MainActivity and set the variable "textWifi" in the MainActivity from BroadcastReceiverListener .  How can I manage that? I hope someone would answer with code to comprehend his answer.

I appreciate any help.

```js
private class BroadcastReceiverListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   if (intent.getAction().equals(
     android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
 if (intent.getAction().equals(
   android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {

  WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

  WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
  final List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
  if (results != null) {
   // list of access points from the last scan
   List<ScanResult> updatedResults = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();
   // pick Wi-Fi access points which begins with these "SV-"
   // characters.
   for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
    String ssid = results.get(i).SSID;
    // Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^KD-(4[0-9]{2}|500)$");
    // Matcher m = p.matcher(ssid);
    // if(m.matches()){}else{}
    if (ssid.startsWith("KD")) {

     updatedResults.add(results.get(i));
    } else {
     textWifi.setText("No route is available.");

    }
   }
   if (updatedResults.size() > 0) {
    String a = deliverBestAccessPoint(updatedResults);
    textWifi.setText(a.toString());
   }
  } else {
   textWifi.setText("There is no WiFi in range.");

  }

  Intent updateIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
  updateIntent.putExtra("broadcast_event", updatedResults);
  context.startActivity(intent);

 }
}

   else if (intent.getAction().equals(
     android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
    
   }
  }
```

Comment: Just create a separate class for the BroadcastReceiverListener and create an instance of it in the main activity. This will allow you to let the String 'a' be a class variable and let you invoke any methods you'd like. If what you are asking is to set a varible in the mainactivity; just create a class varible in the mainactivity and set the value with the '=' operator from the BroadcastReceiverListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to send an Intent from your broadcast receiver to activity:

**EDIT**

Should be something like this in the end. But I don't specify how to convert a List of custom objects into a JSON array and back, it's a completely separate question with its own potential difficulties. You can figure out how to do it with a standard converter, or use some library. I personally prefer [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), it [deals](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples) great with collections of objects without great efforts from your side.

```java
public class BroadcastReceiverListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(
                android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(
                    android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {

                WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

                WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                final List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
                if (results != null) {
                    // list of access points from the last scan
                    List<ScanResult> updatedResults = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();
                    // pick Wi-Fi access points which begins with these "SV-"
                    // characters.
                    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                        String ssid = results.get(i).SSID;
                        // Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^KD-(4[0-9]{2}|500)$");
                        // Matcher m = p.matcher(ssid);
                        // if(m.matches()){}else{}
                        if (ssid.startsWith("KD")) {
                            updatedResults.add(results.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                    Intent updateIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    String extras = convertToJson(updatedResults);
                    updateIntent.putExtra("broadcast_event", extras);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
        }
    }
}

public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        String resultsJson = intent.getStringExtra("broadcast_event");
        if (resultsJson != null) {
            List<ScanResult> results = convertFromJson(resultsJson);
            String a = deliverBestAccessPoint(results);
            textWifi.setText(a.toString());
        } else {
            textWifi.setText("No route is available.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I try to create "Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);" I in onReceive() then I am gettign the error"Duplicate local variable intent" How can I circumvent that? And what about updateResult in putExtra? updatedResults cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: @MrAsker yeah, sorry, forgot you already have one `intent`, just rename the new one to something else. Answer updated.

Comment: And what about "updateResult" in putExtra? updatedResults cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: @MrAsker well, this one's on you :) you've posted a piece of your code, where this variable exists, I just used it, but I have no idea about your app's logic. I guess you know where it comes from in your program?

Comment: I updated my code. Which part of the code shall I remain in the onReceice() and which part in the "onNewIntent" in MainActivity?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to add `MainActivity` as `WeakReference` member of your `BroadcastReceiver` :

```
private class BroadcastReceiverListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public BroadcastReceiverListener (MainActivity mainActivity){
           mainActivityRef = new WeakReference<>(mainActivity);
    }

    private WeakReference<MainActivity> mainActivityRef;
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    if (intent.getAction().equals(
                            android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {

                                  // This method"deliverBestAccessPoint" is in MainActivity class
    MainACtivity mActivity = mainActivityRef.get();
    if(mActivity != null){//could be collected by GC
                                String a = mActivity .deliverBestAccessPoint(updatedResults);
                                //I want to set the "textwifi" varaible in MainActivity
                                mActivity.textWifi.setText(a.toString());
        }
                            }

                    }

                    else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                            android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {

                    }
                }
```

and when registering in MainActivity : `registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiverListener (this), mIntentFilter);`